# Cannot connect to fedora 25 from Windows via TeamViewer 12

Tags: linux, fedora, teamviewer

After installing TeamViewer 12 on machine 192.168.1.10 with the aim of connecting from 192.168.1.11, I've noticed 2 problems:

1 - There is no TeamViewer ID shown via command line info:

```
[root@localhost ~]# teamviewer --info

 TeamViewer                           12.0.71510  (RPM)

 teamviewerd status                   ● teamviewerd.service - TeamViewer remote control daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/teamviewerd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-02-17 09:50:20 EST; 1s ago
  Process: 2432 ExecStart=/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd -d (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2434 (teamviewerd)
    Tasks: 19 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/teamviewerd.service
           └─2434 /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd -d

Feb 17 09:50:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting TeamViewer remote control daemon...
Feb 17 09:50:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: teamviewerd.service: PID file /var/run/teamviewerd.pid not readable (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Feb 17 09:50:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started TeamViewer remote control daemon.

 TeamViewer ID:
Try restarting the TeamViewer daemon (e.g. teamviewer --daemon restart)
```

2 - Restarting the daemon produces the following:

```
2017/02/17 09:40:57.799  1768 4151640000 S   Process received SIGTERM from process: 1
2017/02/17 09:40:57.799  1768 4151640000 S   ShutdownDynGate
2017/02/17 09:40:58.649  1768 4110404416 S   CAcceptServer::HandleAccept: socket closed
2017/02/17 09:40:58.650  1768 3960462144 S   Shutdown complete
2017/02/17 09:40:58.650  1768 4151640000 S   TeamViewer_Service Stop


2017/02/17 09:40:58.665  2172 4151820224 S   Logger started.
2017/02/17 09:40:58.668  2172 4151820224 S   Found 0 Minidump files ...
2017/02/17 09:40:58.668  2172 4151820224 S   Found 0 core dump files ...
2017/02/17 09:40:58.669  2172 4151820224 S+  Thread: IOServiceWorker_0_0
2017/02/17 09:40:58.669  2172 4151820224 S+  Thread: IOServiceWorker_0_2
2017/02/17 09:40:58.669  2172 4151820224 S+  Thread: IOServiceWorker_0_3
2017/02/17 09:40:58.669  2172 4151820224 S+  Thread: IOServiceWorker_0_1
2017/02/17 09:40:58.669  2172 4151820224 S+  Thread: IOServiceWorker_0_4
2017/02/17 09:40:58.669  2172 4151820224 S+  Thread: IOServiceWorker_0_5
2017/02/17 09:40:58.669  2172 4151820224 S+  Thread: IOServiceWorker_0_7
2017/02/17 09:40:58.669  2172 4151820224 S+  Thread: IOServiceWorker_0_6
2017/02/17 09:40:58.672  2172 4151820224 S   systemd: logind service available
2017/02/17 09:40:58.675  2172 4151820224 S   systemd: New seat seat0 [path=/org/freedesktop/login1/seat/seat0, activeSession='c1', canGraphical=1, canTTY=1, canMultiSession=1]
2017/02/17 09:40:58.676  2172 4151820224 S+  DBus: optional property DefaultControlGroup not found
2017/02/17 09:40:58.676  2172 4151820224 S+  DBus: optional property KillProcesses not found
2017/02/17 09:40:58.677  2172 4151820224 S   SystemdSessionInfo: New session SystemdSessionInfo [id=c1 user=gdm state=greeter active=1 reliable=1 infoId=0] [path=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c1 TTY=/dev/tty1 seat=seat0 display= vtnr=1 owner=[SysUser_Lin: gdm [uid=42, gid=42 home=/var/lib/gdm gecos= shell=/sbin/nologin]] idle=1(1487342201259188) active=1 type=wayland class=greeter state=active timestamp=1487341899932512 service=gdm-launch-environment defaultCG= leader=1184 audit=0 remote=0 rHost= rUser= killProc=0]
2017/02/17 09:40:58.678  2172 4151820224 S+  DBus: optional property DefaultControlGroup not found
2017/02/17 09:40:58.678  2172 4151820224 S+  DBus: optional property KillProcesses not found
2017/02/17 09:40:58.678  2172 4151820224 S   SystemdSessionInfo: New session SystemdSessionInfo [id=4 user=root state=user active=1 reliable=1 infoId=1] [path=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/_34 TTY= seat= display= vtnr=4294967295 owner=[SysUser_Lin: root [uid=0, gid=0 home=/root gecos=root shell=/bin/bash]] idle=0(0) active=1 type=tty class=user state=active timestamp=1487342117772927 service=sshd defaultCG= leader=1887 audit=4 remote=1 rHost=192.168.1.11 rUser= killProc=0]
2017/02/17 09:40:58.678  2172 4151820224 S   SysSessionInfoManager: Session Information provided by systemd [priority: 0]
2017/02/17 09:40:58.679  2172 4151820224 S   SysSessionInfoManager: Session Information provided by VT [priority: 2]
2017/02/17 09:40:58.679  2172 4151820224 S+  LateBinding [libX11.so.6]: Loaded library
2017/02/17 09:40:58.679  2172 4151820224 S   XSocket observer: watching /tmp/.X11-unix
2017/02/17 09:40:58.680  2172 4151820224 S   XSocket observer: adding XSession: 1024
2017/02/17 09:40:58.709  2172 4151820224 S+  XSession[1024]: No valid authorisation record found for :1024 in possible files
2017/02/17 09:40:58.712  2172 4151820224 S+  XSession[1024]: No valid authorisation record found for :1024 in possible files
2017/02/17 09:40:58.712  2172 4151820224 S!  XSession[1024]: Unable to get XAuth
2017/02/17 09:40:58.712  2172 4151820224 S   XClient[:1024]: Unable to open XAuthority file "" (err=2)
2017/02/17 09:40:58.712  2172 4151820224 S!  VTSessionInfoProvider: Failed setting TTY for session 1024 on display ':1024'
2017/02/17 09:40:58.712  2172 4151820224 S   SysSessionInfoManager: assigned session 1024 to info provider 'None'
2017/02/17 09:40:58.712  2172 4151820224 S   SysSessionInfoManager: assigned session 1000000 to info provider 'None'
2017/02/17 09:40:58.713  2172 4151820224 S   Starting as daemon
2017/02/17 09:40:58.714  2172 4151820224 S!  AsioSettings::FindExternalIP: found 0 external IPs instead of 1!
2017/02/17 09:40:58.715  2172 4151820224 S   UpdateOnlineState newOnlineValue 0
2017/02/17 09:40:58.715  2172 4151820224 S!  AsioSettings::FindExternalIP: found 0 external IPs instead of 1!
2017/02/17 09:40:58.717  2172 4151820224 S   System uptime: 585 seconds
2017/02/17 09:40:58.718  2172 4151820224 S   MID: Read from disk failed.
2017/02/17 09:40:58.718  2172 4151820224 S   MachineID m=0 - 0



Start:              2017/02/17 09:40:58.719  (UTC-5:00)
Version:            12.0.71510
ID:                 0
Loglevel:           Info (100)
License:            0
Server:             master12.teamviewer.com
IC:                 -924717160
CPU:                AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor
CPU extensions:     g9
OS:                 Lx Fedora 25 Worksta (32-bit)
IP:                 192.168.1.10,192.168.122.1
MID:                -924717160_e2eafd1e_d41d8cd98f00b204
MIDv:               0
Proxy-Settings:     Type=0 IP= User=

2017/02/17 09:40:58.719  2172 4151820224 S   RemoteSettingsMDRelationshipWatchDog: DEVICE ISN'T A MANAGED DEVICE
2017/02/17 09:40:58.719  2172 3972004672 S   RemoteSettingsStore: Cleanup all policies.
2017/02/17 09:40:58.719  2172 4151820224 S   RemoteSettingsStoreListener: Establish connection.
2017/02/17 09:40:58.720  2172 3972004672 S   RemoteSettingsStore::LoadLastReceivedPolicies : Storage Entry Remote_Settings_TVClientSetting_Policy empty
2017/02/17 09:40:58.720  2172 4151820224 S   Using IPC-Port 5939
2017/02/17 09:40:58.720  2172 3972004672 S   RemoteSettingsMDRelationshipWatchDog: DEVICE ISN'T A MANAGED DEVICE
2017/02/17 09:40:58.720  2172 4151820224 S   Updated sessions: [ 1024     ]  [ 1000000  L root ]
2017/02/17 09:40:58.720  2172 4151820224 S   UpdateOnlineState newOnlineValue 0
2017/02/17 09:40:58.720  2172 4151820224 S   Updated sessions: [ 1024     ]  [ 1000000  L root ]
2017/02/17 09:40:58.720  2172 4151820224 S   UpdateOnlineState newOnlineValue 0
2017/02/17 09:40:58.720  2172 4151820224 S   UpdateOnlineState newOnlineValue 0
2017/02/17 09:40:58.720  2172 4151820224 S   UpdateResponseLinux: success 1 updated 0 rev 0
2017/02/17 09:40:58.721  2172 3946826560 S   Using systemd-logind for suspend/resume monitoring
```

Comment: i eventually gave up on this and went back to xrdp.